# git aliases causing "Permission denied" error

Tags: git, gentoo

The following commands

```
$ git co -b newbranch
$ git co oldbranch
```

result in "fatal: cannot exec 'git-co': Permission denied" error.

In the same time,

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ git checkout oldbranch
```

and

```
$ sudo git co -b newbranch
$ sudo git co oldbranch
```

work as expected. Ownership rights for the .git folder are set for the user owning the home folder and 0755/0644 are the mode for .git folder/subfolder/files.

Aliases are defined in `.gitconfig` of the home folder:

```
[alias]
co = checkout
```

There is no difference in `git config -l` output for root or unprivileged user.

What am I missing?

Gentoo 3.0.6 / git 1.7.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997700/git-aliases-causing-permission-denied-error.

Before git runs the aliases it checks the `$PATH`. In case the directory does not exist, or lacks permissions, git produces the `"fatal: cannot exec 'git-co': Permission denied"`.

Good people from the git mailing list also reminded me of a tool, that `strace` can help finding the entry that is returning EACCES, as in: `strace -f -e execve git foobar`

The credit goes to Jeff King from the git mailing list. :)